# Xamarin.Forms Taking picture with Plugin.Media not working

Tags: plugins, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm using the Plugin.Media from @JamesMontemagno version 2.4.0-beta (which fixes picture orientation), it's working on Adroind 4.1.2 (Jelly Bean) and Marshmallow, but NOT on my Galaxy S5 Neo with Android version 5.1.1.

Basically when I take a picture it never returns back on the page from where I started the process; always returns back to the initial home page.

On devices where it works, when I take a picture, I see that first of all the application fires OnSleep, then after taking the picture fires OnResume.
On my device where is NOT working it fires OnSleep and after taking the picture doesn't fire OnResume, it fires the initialization page and then OnStart.
For this reason it doesn't open the page where I was when taking the picture.

What should I do to make sure it fires OnResume returning to the correct page and not OnStart which returns on initial fome page ?

In addition, when I take a picture it takes almost 30 seconds to get back to the code after awaiting TakePhotoAsync process, and it's too slow!

Following my code:

```cs
MyTapGestureRecognizerEditPicture.Tapped += async (sender, e) =>           
{               
            //Display action sheet
            String MyActionResult = await DisplayActionSheet(AppLocalization.UserInterface.EditImage, 
                                                            AppLocalization.UserInterface.Cancel, 
                                                            AppLocalization.UserInterface.Delete,
                                                            AppLocalization.UserInterface.TakePhoto, 
                                                            AppLocalization.UserInterface.PickPhoto);                
            //Execute action result                               
            if (MyActionResult == AppLocalization.UserInterface.TakePhoto)
            {
                //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                //Take photo               
                await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
                if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert(AppLocalization.UserInterface.Alert, AppLocalization.UserInterface.NoCameraAvailable, AppLocalization.UserInterface.Ok);
                }
                else
                {                        
                    var MyPhotoFile = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
                    {
                        Directory = "MyApp",
                        Name = "MyAppProfile.jpg",
                        SaveToAlbum = true,
                        PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Small
                    });                        
                    if (MyPhotoFile != null)
                    {                            
                        //Render image
                        MyProfilePicture.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(MyPhotoFile.Path);                                                        
                        //Save image on database
                        MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                        MyPhotoFile.GetStream().CopyTo(MyMemoryStream);
                        byte[] MyArrBytePicture = MyMemoryStream.ToArray();
                        await SaveProfilePicture(MyArrBytePicture);
                        MyPhotoFile.Dispose();
                        MyMemoryStream.Dispose();                             
                    }                        
                }
            }
            if (MyActionResult == AppLocalization.UserInterface.PickPhoto)
            {
                //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                //Pick photo
                await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
                if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert(AppLocalization.UserInterface.Alert, AppLocalization.UserInterface.PermissionNotGranted, AppLocalization.UserInterface.Ok);
                }
                else
                {                        
                    var MyPhotoFile = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();
                    if (MyPhotoFile != null)
                    {                            
                        //Render image
                        MyProfilePicture.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(MyPhotoFile.Path);
                        //Save image on database
                        MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                        MyPhotoFile.GetStream().CopyTo(MyMemoryStream);
                        byte[] MyArrBytePicture = MyMemoryStream.ToArray();
                        await SaveProfilePicture(MyArrBytePicture);
                        MyPhotoFile.Dispose();
                        MyMemoryStream.Dispose();                                                               
                    }                        
                }
            }                
        };
```

Please help!! We need to deploy this app but we cannot do it with this problem.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perfectly normal to have the Android OS terminate and restart an `Activity`. As you are seeing, your app's `Activity` it will be automatically restarted when the camera app exits and the OS returns control to your app. The odds are it just needed more memory in order to take that photo with the Neo's 16MP camera, you can watch the `logcat` output to confirm that.

> Restarted – It is possible for an activity that is anywhere from paused to stopped in the lifecycle to be removed from memory by Android. If the user navigates back to the activity it must be restarted, restored to its previously saved state, and then displayed to the user.

#### What to do:

So on the Xamarin.Forms `OnStart` lifecycle method you need to restore your application to a valid running state (initializing variables, preforming any bindings, etc...).

#### Plug code:

The Android platform [code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/d4a45bad0fddd445c1178ab35fef38dd90ca812c/Media/Media/Media.Plugin.Android/MediaImplementation.cs) for the `TakePhotoAsync` method looks fine to me, but remember that the memory for that image that is passed back via the `Task` will be doubled as it is marshaled from the ART VM back the Mono VM. Calling `GC.Collect()` as soon as possible after the return will help (but your Activity is restarting anyway...)

```
public async Task<MediaFile> TakePhotoAsync(StoreCameraMediaOptions options)
        {
        ~~~
        var media = await TakeMediaAsync("image/*", MediaStore.ActionImageCapture, options);
```

In turn calls:

```
this.context.StartActivity(CreateMediaIntent(id, type, action, options));
```

Not much less you can really do within the Android OS to popup the Camera.

> In addition, when I take a picture it takes almost 30 seconds to get back to the code after awaiting TakePhotoAsync process, and it's too slow!

Is that on your Neo? Or all devices?

I would call that very suspect (ie. a bug) as even flushing all the Java memory after the native Camera `Intent`/`Activity` and the restart time for your app's `Activity` should not take 30 seconds on a oct-core 1.6 GHz Cortex... but I do not have your device, app and code in front of me....

Comment: I have call GC.Collect() on the line before and line after the calling "TakePhotoAsync" and it looks little bit faster coming back from the camera; but I still have the problem that my application is restarted. Is it maybe something to do with the heap size ? On "Android manifest.xml" I have android:largeHeap="true" and on advanced android build settings I have 1G as Java max heap size. If heap is not the reason what do you think I can do to solve this problem ? Many thanks!!

Comment: Using large heap will not effect anything until ART actually needs it, in `logcat` you will see lines like "`Grow heap (frag case)`" when it is allocating more memory on the Java side of things.

Comment: Is there a reason you can not restore your `Activity`'s state? i.e. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html  via `protected override void OnSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState)`

Comment: just tried to set android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" and launchMode="singleTop", no luck.. I would like to try your suggestion but I'm pretty new on app development and I don't know how to do it and where exactly wite this code. Do you know of any sample code or project I can download or look at ? Many thanks!!!

Comment: Hi @Stefano, did you find any solution for this? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Hi @MoniBhattacharya, yes there was a switch on the mobile phone device : go on phisical mobile developer options and deactivate the option "Do not keep activity"

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Stefano but that we have to set on every device?

Comment: Hi @MoniBhattacharya, not on every device, just the one where I was testing my app. All other devices are ok because as default they don't have developer options activated